# how to create a Tab Delimited CSV?

Tags: excel, export, csv

I need to produce a Tab Delimited CSV of a query pulled from a mySql database. I am using MySQL Query Browser to extract the data as ordenery CSV.

Does anyone know how to convert an ordinery -- comma seperated -- CSV into a Tab Delimited. I can't find a way to do it in nither Excel nor Open Office.

Manny thanks!

p.s. I'm working on a windows 7 machine.

Comment: Excel 2010 has an option to save the file in a `Text (Tab Delimited) (*.txt)` format. (this may be available on previous versions, I just don't have them to test)

Comment: Excel uses the TXT extension for tab-saparated files. But these are not opened in Excel by default, like CSV. In Germany and other places, CSV means semicolon-separated and comma-separated won't open in Excel in any useful way. However, tools such as Piwik save their data tab-separated and give it the CSV extension. Excel kroks it and even Germans are happy for an instant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux?

```
sed 's/,/\t/g' commaDelimited > tabDelimited
```

Windows?

Open notepad, press TAB, select and copy the tab space. Open the CSV in notepad, Edit->Replace... fill `,` in the first box and paste your tab in the second box and just Replace All.

Comment: sorry, only have access to Win7